# Swift : Issue with saving contact with AddressBook - (Xcode6-Beta5)

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, abaddressbook

When I'm trying to store phone number of my new contact, in first step below

```
let multiPhone : ABMutableMultiValueRef = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType)
```

gives

```
'int' is not convertible to 'ABPropertyType'
```

may be as,

```
func ABMultiValueCreateMutable(type: ABPropertyType) -> Unmanaged<ABMutableMultiValueRef>!
```

accepts ABPropertyType which is declared as `typealias ABPropertyType = UInt32` but,

```
var kABMultiStringPropertyType: Int { get }
```

returns Int not UInt32.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
func createMultiStringRef() -> ABMutableMultiValueRef {
     let propertyType: NSNumber = kABMultiStringPropertyType
     return Unmanaged.fromOpaque(ABMultiValueCreateMutable(propertyType.unsignedIntValue).toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as ABMultiValueRef
}
```